# Curl error : No route to host

Tags: php, apache, ssl, curl, guzzle

So we're building a web application in PHP and we're trying to make requests to an external API. Problem is that we're getting a curl error:

> cURL error 7: Failed to connect to external.api.com port 443: No route to host

A little bit of background now.

- We're making requests using [Guzzle](http://guzzlephp.org).
- We're hosting on Apache, which is running on a Linux machine and we're also using SSL.
- The API is also using SSL, therefore the port 443 in error message.
- The HTTP requests include a certificate for authentication.

I've managed to get it running on two different development environments but not on the production one. I suspect the problem is in the configuration of Apache, as if we haven't made it available to make requests to certain IP or port. I have no idea how to check it. I've read that I might have to change the file /etc/network/interface yet I haven't found any info on what to write there.

I've also read I have to run `$ netstat -rn` for answers yet I'm not sure what to look there.

**EDIT:**

Can't even make a simple get request without any parameters and anything.
Yet I can make requests to https://google.com and https://facebook.com. Will write more in a few.

Comment: This is usually a firewall problem. Some corporate environments will even block outbound traffic in production zones.

Comment: @JeffPuckettII `$ sudo ufw status` returns inactive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a lot of debugging and testing all of my code I contacted the service, whose API I was trying to consume.

They were an European service provider and they had whitelisted European IP's. Our production server was in the USA and after they whitelisted our IP, everything worked.

Comment: But you couldn't even access google.com, so how is that related?

Comment: @Houman I was able to access google.com. :)

Answer (score 4):

It worked for me for apache (httpd)

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 3):

`netstat -aln | grep 443` will show if your webserver is listening on that port.

Depending on which webserver you have installed your configuration file, for the site will be at `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`, `/etc/nginx/sites-available/yourSite`, `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` or some other similar paths for apache.

Wherever it is located, your configuration file should contain something like the following:

```
server {
listen 80;
listen 443 ssl;
server_name yourSite.com;
root "/path/to/yourSite";

index index.html index.htm index.php;

charset utf-8;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}

location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

access_log off;
error_log  /path/to/webserver/youSite.error.log error;

sendfile off;

client_max_body_size 100m;

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

    fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
    fastcgi_buffers 4 16k;
    fastcgi_connect_timeout 300;
    fastcgi_send_timeout 300;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
}

location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
}

ssl_certificate     /path/to/yourSite.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /path/to/yourSite.key;
}
```

After changing this file make sure to `sudo service nginx reload` or `sudo service nginx restart` (or the relative apache command).

`sudo service nginx configtest` or `sudo nginx -t` will help with debugging the config file.

Answer (score 0):

After searching for about a whole day I found that the problem was in the **iptables rules**.
In my case the solution was to restore the iptables rules as follows:

1. create a file containing the following text:

   *filter

   :INPUT ACCEPT [10128:1310789]

   :FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]

   :OUTPUT ACCEPT [9631:1361545]

   COMMIT*
2. run the command: `sudo iptables-restore < /path/to/your/previously/created/file`

This will hopefully fix your problem if it is an iptables issue.

Answer (score -2):

today I hava face up the same question, like that
I use  `curl http://localhost:8080`   to check my tomcat can work or not

And it's error   `Failed to connect to ::1: No route to host`

Finally I hava solve it.Obviously, it's the problem of your Apache tomcat.
So you must check your logs firstly. If you found your port was used, find that course and kill it. Then restart your tomcat.

find the course by port:  `netstan -lnp | grep port`
kill course:    `kill -9 ****`